# How can I dispay the data in django admin panel

Tags: python, django

I am creating an eCommerce website but I want to know how can I display a product_name or customer_name in the admin panel.

The concept is that if a customer places an order that it will go to the admin panel. So the other details are displaying properly except product_name or customet_name.

As shown in the below image:

[image]

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
        status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

admin.py

```
class AdminOrders(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['product', 'customer', 'quantity', 'address', 'phone', 'price', 'date', 'status']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `__str__` method in the models `Product` and `Customer`

Example:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call a function it have to return string if you want to display as word.
I know 2 ways to do this
First its **repr** Method

```
def __repr__(self):
     return self.(Model You wanna Display)
```

or **str** Witch is akcually same

```
def __str__(self):
     return self.(Model You wanna Display)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have tried double underscore in order to access the foreign item field  (`product__name`) and (`customer__name`).

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name= models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
   ....
class Customer(models.Model):
   name= models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
   ....

class AdminOrders(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['product__name', 'customer__name', 'quantity', 'address', 'phone', 'price', 'date', 'status']
```

Comment: This has not worked. It throws some errors. Thanks for your answer.